# Read <select> options using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having the following code. From this I want to display the value one two three each in new line.

```
<p><select id="temp">
 <option value="default" selected="selected">--Choose value--</option>
 <option  >one</option>
 <option  >two</option>
 <option >three</option>
</select>
</p>
```

im trying to remove all the tags and putting new line between each value and remove --Choose value-- text

i want ouput as - > one two three(each in new line)

here is what I've tried

```
 tmp = tmp.replace(/<\/p><p>/ig, "<\/p>\n<\/p>");
 tmp = tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
 tmp = tmp.replace(/\n/g, "\n"); 
 tmp = tmp.replace("--Choose an option--","");
```

Comment: You have to explain a bit better. Where and how do you want to display the values? Maybe also *why*? What are you trying to do?

Comment: tmp = tmp.replace(/<\/p><p>/ig, "<\/p>\n<\/p>");
    tmp = tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    tmp = tmp.replace(/\n/g, "\n");
    tmp = tmp.replace("--Choose an option--","");

Comment: im trying to remove all the tags and putting new line between each value

Comment: @Kiran: suggest you update your question to reflect the above :-)

Comment: tell us what it is you want to do in addition to how your attempting to do it. your comment should be in your post. There is an edit button which will allow you to edit the post to put new code etc. in it

Comment: im tried something like the following code  tmp = tmp.replace(/<\/p><p>/ig, "<\/p>\n<\/p>");
    tmp = tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    tmp = tmp.replace(/\n/g, "\n");
    tmp = tmp.replace("--Choose an option--","");

Comment: I'm still not getting what your trying to do can we see what the desired result would look like please , also I put your "what i've tried" in your post please edit your post when adding code rather than posting comments

Comment: @mcgramlim : i cant add new lines

Comment: Why not modify it using true DOM routines?

Comment: Really, **do not used regular expressions for that**. Browsers have a good DOM engine and besides that, regular expressions **cannot** properly handle HTML - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @ Delan Azabani : how can i modify using domain routine , i never tried that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
tmp = tmp.replace("--Choose value--</option>",""); // remove first option
tmp = tmp.replace(/<\/option>/g, "\n"); // replace all </option> with newline
tmp = tmp.replace(/<.*?>/g,""); // remove all other tags
tmp = tmp.replace(/^\s+/g,""); // remove spaces at the beginning of lines
tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length-1); // remove trailing newline
```

This is a bit more compact:

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/.*?<option *>(.*?)<\/option>(?:(?!<option).)*/g, "$1\n");
tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length-1); // remove trailing newline
```

Comment: thanks , this works but one problem is der that it is adding a new line after the last option